# Where does this form of the induction law come from?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations, electromagnetic-induction

I am currently studying a eddy current disk break and came across [this promising paper (PDF, princeton.edu)](https://www.princeton.edu/ssp/joseph-henry-project/eddy-currents/eddy_current_brake.pdf) from 1942.

However, in the first formula a suspicious $4\pi$ appears before the current $U(x,y),$ stating

> Let the eddy currents be confined to a finite region of the sheet which may or may not extend to infinity, and let us define the stream function $U(x,y)$ at any point in the sheet to be the current flowing through any cross section of the sheet extending from $P$ to its edge. The line integral of $\mathbf B$ or $\mathbf H$ over the closed path that bounds this section equals $4\pi U.$ From symmetry the contribution from the upper and lower halves of the path is the same so we may write $$\begin{align}
> 4\pi U = \oint \mathbf B\cdot \mathbf{ds} &= \pm 2 \int_x^\infty B_x~dx \\
> &=\pm 2 \int_y^\infty B_y~dy\end{align}$$
>   where the choice of sign depends on the side of the sheet chosen for the integration.

How can this be explained?

Comment: Can you restate the formula here and provide context? The link might not work for future visitors.

Comment: @ThePhoton added.

Comment: I retract my earlier comment: while the equation $\nabla \times E = -\dot B' - \dot B$ suggests from its lack of $c^{-1}$ that these are not CGS units, the author explicitly mentions on the last page gauss and dyne-cm units, suggesting a preference for such Gaussian units.